# Finding p and q in RSA with a given n, |p-q|<10000

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

I've got an RSA encryption I need to crack, but to do it I need to find the p and q values of an N I am given - it's quite large, around 308 symbols.

I know that N is the product of primes p & q, but I don't know what kind of searching algorithm I'd implement to find the exact p & q that fit |p-q|<10000. Since it needs to be an efficient method, I'm looking for a way that excludes finding ALL possible combinations of p*q = n.

How would I go about doing it? How would I even start with inputting the 308 symbol number anywhere? It's too large to fit any kind of variable in c# for example...

Comment: Fermat factorization?

Comment: Or just brute force searching around $\sqrt{N}$

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0

Comment: For RSA numbers of cryptographic size, simplified Fermat will do: compute $a=\left\lceil\sqrt N\right\rceil$, $p=a+\sqrt{a^2-N}$ which will always be an integer, and $q=a-\sqrt{a^2-N}$.

Comment: I presume symbols means decimal digits?

Answer (score 1):

As @fgrieu said, it will work when ${|p-q|< N^{1/4}}$ , where ${\sqrt N}$ and ${A}$ both are very nearer. then we can take ${A = \sqrt N}$ to start with.

- Let ${A=(p+q)/2}$ , i.e., A is mid point of p and q, which could be nearer to ${\sqrt N}$
- There exist an integer ${x}$ so that, ${A-x=p}$ and ${A+x=q}$
- ${N=pq}$ ${=}$ ${(A-x)(A+x)=A^2-x^2}$
- ${x= \sqrt{A^2-N}}$
- Since we know A and N we can find x and subsequently p and q.